# Send sms throw smpp protocol error

Tags: smpp

I need to send SMS via smpp protocol.

I’m sending an MT message from an emse server to an esme client

My question is about  the SMPP traffic and this error "vendor specific error" ... if it's due to a malformed packet smpp or I must refer to my SMPP provider? any explanation please ?

I attached a dump traffic on Wireshark for more details.[link to pcap file](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/restcomm/5YwvKVtkloY)

Answer (score 1):

The packet is well formed and has no issue. Usually in these types of errors i would go and ask the provider for the exact meaning of the error since the error codes differ from a vendor to another.

However i did notice something odd in the trace, the IP: 10.10.32.66 did not send any enquire link through out the whole wireshark session.